# Downloading files from google drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file from google drive
I created google credentials oath and all,

I am perfectly able to get the list of files on the drive
However, when I try to download a file, i get error 500

this is my code to download:

```
  private static void downloadFile(Drive service,String fileId) {
    try {

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.csv");
        service.files().export(fileId, "text/csv")
                .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // An error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the resulting response:

```
    com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMedia(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:380)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Export.executeMedia(Drive.java:2464)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAsInputStream(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:523)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Export.executeMediaAsInputStream(Drive.java:2459)
    at com.mobile.stringExtractor.core.DriveQuickstart.downloadFile(DriveQuickstart.java:158)
    at com.mobile.stringExtractor.core.DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I have no clue why it try to do something with json when i am trying to download a google sheet file.

```
A few notes:
1. the file does exist and is not empty
2. I did authorize google drive for the said account with scopes DriveScopes.Drive
3. I do manage to download the list of files just fine
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you turn on logging and then paste the http request

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/ExponentialBackOffPolicy), it means that the servers are temporarily available. You can just implement an [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff?hl=en) for this kind of error to resend the request.

> The idea is that the servers are only temporarily unavailable, and they should not be overwhelmed when they are trying to get back up.
>
> The default implementation requires back off for 500 and 503 status codes. Subclasses may override if different status codes are required.